# fetch data from one controller to another

Tags: html, angularjs

I have two controller as menucontroller and ordercontroller. I am passing the data from menu to order its ok, but while passing the same data it's adding one more line instead of increasing quantity.

I have some values as name, price, quantity.

Comment: Please use Service to share the data between controller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should consider using a [provider](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/providers) (service or factory) to share data between controllers. Consider the following example:

#### Factory Example

```
// shared factory
angular.module('myApp').factory('myFactory', myFactory);

// anything exposed by this factory will be available
// to any controller that injects it
function myFactory() {
  var factory = this;

  factory.menu = {food: {}, etc: []};
  factory.method = someMethod;

  return factory;

  function someMethod() { ... }
}
```

#### Controller Example

```
// Controller Example
angular.module('myApp').controller('myController', myController);

function myController(myFactory) {
  var menu = myFactory.menu; // exposed by our factory and is available
  myFactory.someMethod();
}
```

Comment: Instead of injecting the controller we can directly access those controller data by simply injecting the service for which controller we want the access like consider i have 2 controller and 2 services than we can inject those both services in the all first controller and we can access there scope easily in another controller...

Comment: @NitinAgarwal That's exactly what my answer suggests :) The answer above injects a service (or in this case a factory) to share data to a given controller. That service can also be injected into other controllers to share data. If that route worked for you, feel free to accept this answer :)

Comment: Thank You @Sean3z  .I have already completed that functionality by injecting the Services into controllers.